# Referencing from other json object (like SQL join) in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I need to refer some values across json objects, like we would do in SQL tables (join).

Below is a part my markup:

```
<div data-ng-app="myApp1">
<div data-ng-controller="MyController">
    <div data-ng-repeat="item in items" >{{ item.Title }}
        <ul data-ng-repeat="tag in item.tags">
            <!--<li style="background-color: {{ tags[tag.Title].Category }}">{{tag.Title}}</li> NOT SURE ABOUT THIS PART-->
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Javascript (Angular)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp1',[]);

myApp.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
$scope.categories = [
{
    "Category": "Car",
    "Background": "red"
},
{
    "Category": "Bus",
    "Background": "green"
},
{
    "Category": "Bike",
    "Background": "blue"
}
];

$scope.tags = [
{
    "Title" : "Ferrari",
    "Category": "Car"
},
{
    "Title" : "Mercedez",
    "Category": "Car"
},
{
    "Title" : "Mercedez",
    "Category": "Bus"
},
{
    "Title" : "BMW",
    "Category": "Bike"
},
{
    "Title" : "BMW",
    "Category": "Car"
},
{
    "Title" : "Volvo",
    "Category": "Car"
}

]

$scope.items = [
{
    "Title": "Item 1",
    "tags": [
        {
            "Title" : "BMW"
        },
        {
            "Title" : "Volvo"
        },
        {
            "Title" : "Mercedez"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "Title": "Item 2",
    "tags": [
        {
            "Title" : "Mercedez"
        },
        {
            "Title" : "Ferrari"
        }
    ]
}
]

});
```

Complete Fiddle here:http://jsfiddle.net/cyberpks/n61a1q5m/7/

I need to set `background-color` for `tag` in `items` which will refer to `tags.Title` which further refers from `categories.Background`

Comment: You have two `Mercedez` in tag with two different category ?? how come items will know which category he belongs to ?  same for `BMW`

Comment: need to map your arrays to hashmap or use filtering functions. Alternatively change API to deliver what you need

Answer (score 0):

First map the `categories` to a category colors object, then map the `tags` to a `colors` object that can look up the color in the category colors

```
var catColors ={};
$scope.categories.forEach(function(cat){
    catColors[cat.Category]= cat.Background;
})
$scope.carColors ={};

$scope.tags.forEach(function(tag){    
    $scope.carColors[tag.Title] = catColors[tag.Category];
});
```

Usage:

```
 <li style="background-color: {{ carColors[tag.Title] }}">{{tag.Title}}</li>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n61a1q5m/8/)**</kbd>